# Duplicate notification for the same reputation event after editing question title

Tags: bug, ios-app, achievements-dialog

#### Step to reproduce

1. Answer a question;
2. Answer gets accepted or upvoted;
3. Receive notification in the app;
4. Change the title of the question;
5. Notification is duplicated with updated title.

#### Expected behavior

When going into notifcations you should see only one entry for that reputation event.

#### Actual behavior

You get two notification entries.

In the screen notice the two entries for the same question, the one related to EF. After answering I have changed the name to make it more searchable for future questions and i've noticed it.

> [image: Duplicate Notification]

---

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Comment: This is the same for upvotes too. Just change the title.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks for point out:) updated

Comment: Do you get it in the web site too, or just in the app?

Comment: For me it is just in the app. Do you get it in Android too? @Sha

Comment: @ShadowWizard Same for me

Comment: @Patrick still didn't have chance to test, but most likely android app will behave the same.